# Modify prompt based on value

Tags: bash, prompt

Suppose I have an environment variable defined in .bash_profile like this:

`PS1='\[\e[31;1m\][\u@\h \T \w] \[\e[0m\]'`

This variable makes my Linux prompt show certain information, like thes:

`[jeff@node21 01:48:30 ~]`
`[jeff@node22 01:48:30 ~]`
`[jeff@node23 01:48:30 ~]`
`[jeff@master 01:48:30 ~]`

When the word "master" appears, I want to capitalize it (I am not to do any work on that node and I want it to stand out when I forget to `rsh` to other nodes).

I can't use `sed` on the variable `PS1`, because that doesn't contain the word "master" in it.

Ultimately, *I want the prompt to be capitalized when I'm on node "master". Is there a way to evaluate variable "PS1", manipulate the string, and then re-assign it so the prompt works?*

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a recent version of `bash`, you can accomplish this with `PROMPT_COMMAND` and using a variable in `PS1` instead of `\h`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
  myhost=$(hostname)
  if [[ $myhost == master ]]; then
    myhost=${myhost^^}
  fi
'

PS1='\[\e[31;1m\][\u@$myhost \T \w] \[\e[0m\]'
```

Whatever is in `PROMPT_COMMAND` is run before every prompt is written. The above definition sets `myhost` to the output of `hostname`, and if `myhost` is *master*, it gets uppercased by the `${var^^}` expansion.

Comment: In Bash versions older than 4, to capitalize use `tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`

Comment: or `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` -- http://man.cx/tr

Answer (score 3):

an alternative approach would be

```
PS1='\[\e[31;1m\][\u@$(hostname | perl -pe "\$_ = uc if m/master/") \T \w] \[\e[0m\]'
```

i admit that my suggestion is not so well structured like Thor's one, but it's basically nice to know that

```
$(cmd)
```

is the syntax for command substitution, like generally in `bash`.

There is also a nice [howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) which only deals with the configuration of bash's prompt. It's definitely worth reading.